# Как организовать доступ и изменение данных для случая двух источников данных?

Tags: python, redis

У меня есть админка, она состоит из одного поля с id=“notepad”. Из набора CRUD доступны только операции чтения и изменения.

Для хранения данных используются: redis, postgres

Чтение:

```
1. Пользователь открывает страничку админки.
2. Уходит запрос значения notepad в redis
3. Если данные приходят из redis, то отрисовывается страничка админки
4. Если данные из redis не приходят, то уходит запрос в postgres
5. Если данные из postgres приходят, то отрисовывается страничка админки
6. Если данные из postgres не приходят, то всё равно отрисовывается страничка админки, но с пустым полем notepad
```

Обновление:

```
1. Пользователь заполняет поле notepad
2. Данные записываются в redis
3. Данные записываются в postgres
```

Мне кажется, в операции записи я произвожу лишние действия. Видио, нужно поставить какое-нибудь условие. Но я не понимаю как это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста.

В частности беспокоит меня такой кейс:

```
1. В redis есть данные для поля notepad
2. В postgres есть те же данные для поля notepad
3. Пользователь записывает новые данные в это поле.
4. В redis не успешно
5. В postgres успешно
6. В результате когда пользователь зайдёт на страничку, он получит старые данные из redis, а в это время в postgres хранятся совсем другие актуальные данные
```

Вот репозиторий: https://github.com/zlodiak/flask_adminka_with_redis

Обновление данных происходит здесь: https://github.com/zlodiak/flask_adminka_with_redis/blob/master/app.py#L111

Чтение данных происходит здесь: https://github.com/zlodiak/flask_adminka_with_redis/blob/master/app.py#L20

или, если так удобнее, то:

Обновление:

```
 @app.route('/submit_notepad_request', methods=['POST'])
def submit_notepad_request():
    with DB_connection() as db_connect:
        notepad = request.values.get('notepad')
        id_auth_user = request.cookies.get('flask_adminka_authorized_user_id')
        with redis_instance.pipeline() as pipe:
            pipe.multi()
            pipe.set('notepad:' + id_auth_user, notepad)
            pipe.execute()
            redis_instance.bgsave()
        db_cursor = db_connect.cursor()
        req = "select * from options where user_id=" + id_auth_user
        db_cursor.execute(req)
        record = db_cursor.fetchone() 
        if record:
            try: 
                req = "UPDATE options SET notepad='" + notepad + "' WHERE user_id=" + str(id_auth_user)
                db_cursor.execute(req);
                db_connect.commit()
                resp = Response('submit notepad is complete')
                return resp
            except:
                resp = Response('failed')
                return resp
```

Чтение:

```
 @app.route('/admin')
def admin():    
    if 'flask_adminka_authorized_user_id' not in request.cookies:
        return redirect('/', code=404)
    id_auth_user = request.cookies.get('flask_adminka_authorized_user_id')
    admin_forms_values = {
        'firstname': None,
        'lastname': None,
        'notepad': None,
    }
    firstname = redis_instance.get('firstname:' + id_auth_user)
    lastname = redis_instance.get('lastname:' + id_auth_user)
    notepad = redis_instance.get('notepad:' + id_auth_user)
    if firstname and lastname and notepad:
        admin_forms_values['firstname'] = firstname.decode("utf-8")
        admin_forms_values['lastname'] = lastname.decode("utf-8")
        admin_forms_values['notepad'] = notepad.decode("utf-8")      
        return render_template('admin.html', admin_forms_values=admin_forms_values)
    with DB_connection() as db_connect:
        db_cursor = db_connect.cursor()
        try:
            request_form = "select * from options where user_id='" + id_auth_user + "'"
            db_cursor.execute(request_form)
            record = db_cursor.fetchone()
            admin_forms_values['firstname'] = record[1] if record[1] else ''
            admin_forms_values['lastname'] = record[2] if record[2] else ''
            admin_forms_values['notepad'] = record[3] if record[3] else ''
            print('log: successfull retrieve admin_forms_values', admin_forms_values)
        except:
            print('log: failed retrieve admin_forms_values', admin_forms_values)

        return render_template('admin.html', admin_forms_values=admin_forms_values)
```

Comment: записывай данные в кеш после успешного сохранения в базе

Comment: @eri в этом случае не успешной записи в редис, неактуальные данные всё равно будут содержаться в редис